# Exchange 2003 automated mailbox size report

Tags: exchange, monitoring, mailbox, report

I have a question if I may. I have been looking for a while for something that can report user mailbox sizes and percentage used against their quota or something that can warn me when a mailbox is getting close to the quota. I know the user receives a warning but how can I send that same warning a centralized mailbox so we can be pro-active in our support. Either a script or an application that can do this will be helpful. Unfortunately my scripting skills are useless for something this complex. Any ideas of what can be used will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One surefire way to keep the mailboxes to small sizes is publishing the top 10-25 in size, mailbox owners on the intranet with some nice ranking;) Nothing works as good as a little guilt and shame:)

As to your question i don't have any good ideas other than script it yourself with some good ol VBScript, heres how you get the sizes from a 2000/2003 Exchange server.
Check out the part **Getting Mailboxes Size**
http://www.msexchange.org/articles/Scripting-Exchange-VBScript-ADSI-Part3.html

This should be pretty simple to use in a script where you query each user the script finds and asks the AD server what the quota limits are and if its in an allowed threshold.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I have made several vbscripts on mailboxes.
They can be found here:

http://deludi.nl/blog/vbscript/active-directory/exchange-active-directory-vbscript/active-directory-and-wmi-vbscript-to-enumerate-all-mailboxes-and-their-size-of-your-ad-domain/